# Explicitly defaulted constructors in empty and non-empty struct

Tags: c++

The following program compiles only if I pass the `-DA=1` flag to the compiler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct element {
    element() = default;

    element(element&&) = default;
    element& operator=(element&&) = default;

    element(const element&) = delete;
    element& operator=(const element&) = delete;

    #if A
    std::vector<int> v;
    #endif
};

int main() {
    std::vector<element> source(10), destination;
    std::move(std::begin(source), std::end(source), std::back_inserter(destination));
}
```

If `-DA=0` is passed then compilation fails with the error:

```
stl_algobase.h:373:4: error: static assertion failed: type is not assignable
```

[Check it out on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a4aa8dfb2db03c9)

It fails when using GCC 4.9 or Clang 3.4.

Does the presence of a member variable affect the behavior of explicitly defaulted constructors?

#### Update

I was using stdlibc++ for both GCC and Clang. The code compiles when using Clang 3.4 and libc++.

Comment: Self promotion... tsk tsk tsk...

Comment: [Does work with clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43232544f059aa37) if you use libc++ instead of libstdc++

Comment: Compiles correctly in g++ 4.8.3 both ways

Comment: @Praetorian [It works when using Clang with libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f037e6be3e83bf06).

Comment: The error messages on Coliru suggest that the problem is with `std::is_copy_assignable<element>`

Comment: @StackedCrooked Isn't that what I said too? :) Anyway, gcc seems happy even if you replace the `vector` data member with `int i = 0;`. But get rid of the NSDMI and the same error occurs. Seems to have something to do with `element` being trivially constructible.

Comment: also how is `std::move` taking 3 arguments?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: It's the algorithm [`std::move()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move). It functions similarly to [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Comment: @sharth I see. In the N3337's index this version is listed as "move *move*"  !

Answer (score 4):

This version of `std::move` is:

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
    OutputIterator move(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
    OutputIterator result);
```

`OutputIterator` properties are defined by [output.iterators], in particular the following expression must be valid:

```
*r = o
```

where `r` is the output iterator.

Based on the error messages shown by Coliru, it appears as if the library is checking `std::is_copy_assignable<element>`, which is of course false.

This appears to be a bug; the move ought to work using the move-assignment operator.

Compare the following in the same Coliru:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<element> e(1);
    std::vector<element> d(1);

    *e.begin() = std::move( *d.begin() );       // A=1 OK   A=0 OK
    std::move(d.begin(), d.end(), e.begin());   // A=1 OK   A=0 errors
}
```

The definition of `std::move` (3 arguments) includes that for each index it performs `*(result + n) = std::move( *(first + n) );` . So if my first line is valid then my second line should also be valid.

Comment: NB. I'm not sure why the library is only checking `is_copy_assignable<element>` in the A=0 case , perhaps trawling through the `stl_algobase.h` etc. is required

Comment: @JonathanWakely should be able to answer this as the [commit](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2013-11/txt2HyvK9Zcxl.txt) was his.